# Is it possible to save a complete state of a QApplication and reload it afterward?

Tags: python, pyqt, save, load, pickle

I'm facing an issue to save a complete state of a Qt window application. 
What I'd like to di is save a file which contains everything about the window and then, if I want, I could reload it to obtain the same window with all previous variable in it (reload their values)

For instance, I've this code

```
import pickle
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.color = self.centralWidget.palette().color(QPalette.Background)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.plotview = QGroupBox(" ")
        self.layout_plotview = QVBoxLayout()
        self.test = QLineEdit('0.0')
        self.Button_Loadstate = QPushButton('Load state')
        self.Button_Savestate = QPushButton('Save state')
        self.layout_plotview.addWidget(self.test)
        self.layout_plotview.addWidget(self.Button_Savestate)
        self.layout_plotview.addWidget(self.Button_Loadstate)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.layout_plotview)


        self.Button_Savestate.clicked.connect(self.Savestate)
        self.Button_Loadstate.clicked.connect(self.Loadstate)


    def Savestate(self,):
        fileName = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,'Save State')
        if  (fileName[0] == '') :
            return
        file_pi = open(fileName[0] + '.state', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self, file_pi)
        file_pi.close()
        return

    def Loadstate(self,):
        fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Load State' , "", "data files (*.state)")
        if  (fileName[0] == '') :
            return
        filehandler = open(fileName[0], 'rb')
        self = pickle.load(filehandler)
        filehandler.close()
        return


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which give me this :

[image]

I create a window with a QLineEdit and two buttons (one for saving and one for loading). Then I use pickle to save the `self` of the `SurfViewer` class instance in a `Savestate`function. Then I try to reload the previous state with pickle `self = pickle.load(filehandler)`. It seems that it will not be so simple because I cannot assign the `self` variable.
If anyone could give some insights to perform that without saving every variable by hand.

Comment: You can use PyQt5.QtCore.QSettings (May help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932368/saving-the-state-of-a-qt-application-to-a-file )

Comment: You [cannot pickle widgets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22889876/984421), so your only solution is to explicitly save each item of data that you're interested in. There are a few convenience methods like [QMainWindow.saveState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#saveState) that may help a little - but other than that, you will have to write everything yourself.

Comment: Ho no ... On the example I shown their are a few things to save but in my full application, their are too many. So I cannot save each item explicitly. The other thing that bother me is when all variables are reloaded, i need also to perform a redrawing of all figures in the windows. I will probably just save some data and use'em in an other simpler application though.

Comment: You can pickle PyQt5 widgets.  I do it all the time.  To do so you need to add custom `__getstate__ / __setstate__` methods.  Here's something I'm experimenting with.  Code that does this automatically for all qualifying setVariable(val) / variable() type attributes of a PyQt5 object: https://github.com/enjoysmath/pyqt_pickle.  Thus there are not "too many" any more!